# symfony2 2.7 define asset path

Tags: symfony, twig

How do i define asset path for twig?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>

        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="{{ asset('iphone5sSmall.png') }}" width="300" height="659"  alt=""/>
    </body>
</html>
```

i just download a symfony2 and see base.html.twig, how can i define the deflaut path for asset function?

i had tried define that in config.yml but not successful

Comment: What do you mean by `asset path`? Where to find your files or what web-path it would be?

Answer (score 1):

it would be much easier if you add your config.yml however you can use console for adding a path to assets :

```
app/console assets:install path
```

Comment: as you know you can do it by config.yml . add config.yml content for helping